# How can I make a table responsive in Semantic-UI-React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, semantic-ui-react

Right now I have a long and wide table. It takes all of the 16 spots in the grid and looks good but When I over-ride some data to `Table.cell` . It can break the width of table . Like this:

[image]

Can any body help me how to solve this problem ?

```
 <Table>
  <Table.Body>
    <Table.Row>
      <Responsive as={Table.Cell} minWidth={Responsive.onlyMobile.minWidth}>
      Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
      </Responsive>
      <Responsive as={Table.Cell} minWidth={Responsive.onlyMobile.minWidth}>Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</Responsive>
      <Responsive as={Table.Cell} minWidth={Responsive.onlyMobile.minWidth}>
        <Responsive
          as={Table.Cell}
          minWidth={Responsive.onlyMobile.minWidth}
        >
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
          Bazfasdfssafsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
        </Responsive>
      </Responsive>
    </Table.Row>
  </Table.Body>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `style={{ overflow: auto }}` to `<Table.body />`